# React JS API item.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, } from "react";

function ProductDetail({match}) {
useEffect(() => {
  fetchItem();
  // console.log(match)
}, );

const fetchItem = async () => {
  const fetchItem = await fetch(`https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/item/get?id={{itemid}}`);
  const item = await fetchItem.json();

  console.log(item);
}

  return (
    <div className="containter productsDetails">
      <h1>Product Detail</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLcis.png)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

function Products() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const apiGet = () => {
    fetch(`https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/items/popular`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setData(json);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    apiGet();
  },[])

  return (
    <div>

      <div>
          <ul>
              {data.map(item =>
              <li  key={item.id}>
                  <Link to={`/products/${item.id}`}>{item.item}</Link>
              </li>
                )}
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

I have tried every way I can find online.

I am unable to map into the entries object of this API. I would like to map to the 3 array objects.

So that I can {match} using an ID when I click one of them.

The routing is working. But I can not display any of the data on the screen. In Console it is displaying.

He is the API fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/items/popular

Comment: As it is now, I think your question is a bit too vague. Please add some details, share what you have already tried, add some relevant code (possibly in the form of a minimal reproducible example), any error message you get, etc.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. We can't really help if we can't see your code. [Add it to the question as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002), not as an image.

Comment: Can we see what you are getting in console

Comment: I am unable to add images of the console. I do not know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use map function on object. map only works for arrays.

Here's the [link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-margulis-21fw17?file=/src/App.js) how it should be

Comment: Thank you that has worked.

Please can I also ask. 

Now how do I get to display that specific fetched data when clicked in the new page via match

I have setup my routes and they are working well.

When a user clicks the links. They open in a new page, and the URL is indeed showing the corrent ID of the item clicked. 

But getting the data to display is the issue now.

Please find my latest update with the code on the product detail page